Azure function is not deployed from VS - No HTTP triggers found
I am new to Azure function as well as python. I have created a Azure function using python v2 programming model and I can execute it successfully from VS code. But when try deploying either using VS code extension and CLI, the deployment is getting succeeded but the function doesn't appear. I have tried most of the options suggested online but not has resolved this issue. I have been stuck at this for quite a while. Any assistance would be appreciated.
Note: As I function is using consumption plan I can't really use kudu to check the wwwroot directory. I have tried manually syncing the triggers using the API as suggested but still the function didn't appear.
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import psycopg2
import flask
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.route(route="InsertFileInfo")
def InsertFileInfo(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    # Connection string information
    host = "host"
    dbname = "dbname"
    user = "dbname"
    password = "password"
    sslmode = "require"
    # Construct connection string
    conn_string = "host={0} user={1} dbname={2} password={3} sslmode={4}".format(host, user, dbname, password, sslmode)
    # Get JSON payload from the HTTP request
    try:
        payload = req.get_json()
    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse("Invalid JSON payload", status_code=400)
    file_details = payload.get('fileDetails', {})
    sender = payload.get('sender', {})
    workflow_id = payload.get('workflowID')
    workflow_event = payload.get('workflowEvent')
    # Extracting values from nested dictionaries
    created_at = file_details.get('createdAt')
    file_id = file_details.get('fileID')
    file_key = file_details.get('key')
    receiver_sha256_hash = file_details.get('receiverSHA256Hash')
    application_id = sender.get('applicationID')
    zone = sender.get('zone')
    # Connect to the database
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
     # SQL query to insert data into the table
        insert_query = """INSERT INTO file_info (created_at, file_id, file_key, receiver_sha256_hash, 
                            sender_applicationid, zone, workflow_id, workflow_event) 
                            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        # Data tuple to be inserted
        data_tuple = (created_at, file_id, file_key, receiver_sha256_hash, application_id, zone, workflow_id, workflow_event)
        # Executing the SQL command
        cursor.execute(insert_query, data_tuple)
        # Committing the changes to the database
        connection.commit()
        # Close Cursor and Connection
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        return func.HttpResponse("Data inserted successfully", status_code=200)
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(str(e))
        return func.HttpResponse("Error inserting data", status_code=500)

local.settings.json file:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=cftwebhook;AccountKey=M2fgac7RMXqWEXDhfxcTP2MjogasutKC4PZzrLCoHerChvVH6SDXuEnCnxOh7DX1R7Ezst4s/LhM+ASt3Y7PYQ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}

host json file:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}

Note: I seeing an below error when I open the host json file.
enter image description here
Requirement.txt:
azure-functions==1.18.0
Flask==3.0.0
psycopg2==2.9.9
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9


Output:
PS C:\Sivanesan> func azure functionapp publish cftwebhook

Getting site publishing info...

[2024-04-05T04:05:42.430Z] Starting the function app deployment...

Creating archive for current directory...

Performing remote build for functions project.

Deleting the old .python_packages directory

Could not find gozip for packaging. Using DotNetZip to package. This may cause problems preserving file permissions when using in a Linux based environment.

Uploading 3.99 KB [###############################################################################]

Remote build in progress, please wait...

Updating submodules.

Preparing deployment for commit id '8da31d4a-5'.

PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False

PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot

Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted

Running oryx build...

Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.11 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages

Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx

You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues

Oryx Version: 0.2.20230210.1, Commit: a49c8f6b8abbe95b4356552c4c884dea7fd0d86e, ReleaseTagName: 20230210.1

Build Operation ID: 650efe847b4b9431

Repository Commit : 8da31d4a-5cb9-4b4d-a70c-9db4219f620c

OS Type : bullseye

Image Type : githubactions

Detecting platforms...

Detected following platforms:

python: 3.11.8

Source directory : /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted

Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot

Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.8/bin/python3.11

Creating directory for command manifest file if it does not exist

Removing existing manifest file

Running pip install...

Done in 12 sec(s).

[04:05:55+0000] Collecting azure-functions==1.18.0

[04:05:55+0000] Using cached azure_functions-1.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (173 kB)

[04:05:55+0000] Collecting Flask==3.0.0

[04:05:55+0000] Using cached flask-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (99 kB)

[04:05:55+0000] Collecting psycopg2==2.9.9

[04:05:55+0000] Using cached psycopg2-2.9.9.tar.gz (384 kB)

[04:05:56+0000] Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.9.9

[04:05:56+0000] Using cached psycopg2_binary-2.9.9-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)

[04:05:56+0000] Collecting itsdangerous>=2.1.2

[04:05:56+0000] Using cached itsdangerous-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)

[04:05:56+0000] Collecting Werkzeug>=3.0.0

[04:05:56+0000] Downloading werkzeug-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (226 kB)

[04:05:56+0000] Collecting blinker>=1.6.2

[04:05:56+0000] Downloading blinker-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)

[04:05:56+0000] Collecting click>=8.1.3

[04:05:56+0000] Using cached click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)

[04:05:56+0000] Collecting Jinja2>=3.1.2

[04:05:56+0000] Downloading Jinja2-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)

[04:05:56+0000] Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0

[04:05:56+0000] Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.5-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (28 kB)

[04:05:56+0000] Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2

[04:05:56+0000] Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): started

[04:06:05+0000] Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): finished with status 'done'

[04:06:05+0000] Created wheel for psycopg2: filename=psycopg2-2.9.9-cp311-cp311-linux_x86_64.whl size=490670 sha256=fb3a4c4671c5e98d77e3d855f216298afa3bde8c4121a0657c18a8668138258c

[04:06:05+0000] Stored in directory: /usr/local/share/pip-cache/wheels/ab/34/b9/78ebef1b3220b4840ee482461e738566c3c9165d2b5c914f51

[04:06:05+0000] Successfully built psycopg2

[04:06:05+0000] Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, Werkzeug, Jinja2, itsdangerous, click, blinker, psycopg2-binary, psycopg2, Flask, azure-functions

[04:06:06+0000] Successfully installed Flask-3.0.0 Jinja2-3.1.3 MarkupSafe-2.1.5 Werkzeug-3.0.2 azure-functions-1.18.0 blinker-1.7.0 click-8.1.7 itsdangerous-2.1.2 psycopg2-2.9.9 psycopg2-binary-2.9.9

WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 24.0 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.8/bin/python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Not a vso image, so not writing build commands

Preparing output...

Copying files to destination directory '/home/site/wwwroot'...

Done in 0 sec(s).

Removing existing manifest file

Creating a manifest file...

Manifest file created.

Copying .ostype to manifest output directory.

Done in 12 sec(s).

Running post deployment command(s)...

Generating summary of Oryx build

Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log

The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build

Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).

Linux Consumption plan has a 1.5 GB memory limit on a remote build container.

To check our service limit, please visit https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits

Writing the artifacts to a squashfs file

Parallel mksquashfs: Using 1 processor

Creating 4.0 filesystem on /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs, block size 131072.

[===============================================================\] 576/576 100%

Exportable Squashfs 4.0 filesystem, gzip compressed, data block size 131072

compressed data, compressed metadata, compressed fragments,

compressed xattrs, compressed ids

duplicates are removed

Filesystem size 5302.05 Kbytes (5.18 Mbytes)

35.94% of uncompressed filesystem size (14751.09 Kbytes)

Inode table size 5697 bytes (5.56 Kbytes)

29.56% of uncompressed inode table size (19270 bytes)

Directory table size 5688 bytes (5.55 Kbytes)

38.25% of uncompressed directory table size (14870 bytes)

Number of duplicate files found 31

Number of inodes 593

Number of files 532

Number of fragments 58

Number of symbolic links 0

Number of device nodes 0

Number of fifo nodes 0

Number of socket nodes 0

Number of directories 61

Number of ids (unique uids + gids) 1

Number of uids 1

root (0)

Number of gids 1

root (0)

Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...

SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE placeholder blob scm-latest-CFTWebhook.zip located

Uploading built content /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs for linux consumption function app...

Resetting all workers for cftwebhook.azurewebsites.net

Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.

Remote build succeeded!

[2024-04-05T04:06:19.747Z] Syncing triggers...

Functions in CFTWebhook:


enter image description here
I have tried most of the suggestion provided online but couldn't get this working
Regards
Sivanesan

Updated answer:-
With psycopg2:-
When I added psycopg2 the Function Trigger was Not Found:-

This due to the on going issue and Bug with Azure Functions Python V2 function refer here. Whenever customer's are importing external package in their Python V2 function trigger the Function is not visible on the portal. I request you to wait for an update in the github issue or post your comment in the same issue to get resolution.
Without psycopg2
Try using the code below and deploy your Function to the consumption based Function app:-
My Function HttpTrigger code:-
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="InsertFileInfo")
def InsertFileInfo(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    # Connection string information
    host = "host"
    dbname = "dbname"
    user = "dbname"
    password = "password"
    sslmode = "require"
    # Construct connection string
    conn_string = "host={0} user={1} dbname={2} password={3} sslmode={4}".format(host, user, dbname, password, sslmode)
    # Get JSON payload from the HTTP request
    try:
        payload = req.get_json()
    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse("Invalid JSON payload", status_code=400)
    file_details = payload.get('fileDetails', {})
    sender = payload.get('sender', {})
    workflow_id = payload.get('workflowID')
    workflow_event = payload.get('workflowEvent')
    # Extracting values from nested dictionaries
    created_at = file_details.get('createdAt')
    file_id = file_details.get('fileID')
    file_key = file_details.get('key')
    receiver_sha256_hash = file_details.get('receiverSHA256Hash')
    application_id = sender.get('applicationID')
    zone = sender.get('zone')
    # Connect to the database
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
     # SQL query to insert data into the table
        insert_query = """INSERT INTO file_info (created_at, file_id, file_key, receiver_sha256_hash, 
                            sender_applicationid, zone, workflow_id, workflow_event) 
                            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        # Data tuple to be inserted
        data_tuple = (created_at, file_id, file_key, receiver_sha256_hash, application_id, zone, workflow_id, workflow_event)
        # Executing the SQL command
        cursor.execute(insert_query, data_tuple)
        # Committing the changes to the database
        connection.commit()
        # Close Cursor and Connection
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        return func.HttpResponse("Data inserted successfully", status_code=200)
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(str(e))
        return func.HttpResponse("Error inserting data", status_code=500)

Output:-



Make sure the below setting is present in your function app Configuration setting or Environment Variables:-
"name": "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags",
"value": "EnableWorkerIndexing",


Hi @SiddeshDesai - Thanks for the quick response. Did you test function locally or in the portal because you are not importing psycopg2 in the code. I can see the function after using your code but its failing as psycopg2 wasn't imported.
2024-04-05T08:37:30Z   [Information]   Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2024-04-05T08:37:30Z   [Error]   name 'psycopg2' is not defined


It tried it locally and in Portal both, In both cases the Function loads correctly. I am using Python 3.11 Locally and my function app is deployed with Python 3.11 Consumption based plan

If the issue is happening with the package, It is a bug in Azure Python Function v2- Where if you import any package the Function does not load, Refer the Github issue on the same bug here- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1262#issuecomment-2010338248

Can you check the code which you have shared as you are not importing psycopg2

Thanks for the direction Siddhesh. I was able to resolve the issue by switching from psycopg2 to psycopg2-binary

I had the same issue. It turned out that the exact version numbers were missing in my requirements.txt. This happened because I added the module names manually and had not created the file using pip freeze > requirements.txt
